# Remove default linker flags in Rust

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

Is there a way to remove problematic linker flags in the cargo build command? I'm trying to cross-compile a binary on windows for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` but linking fails with the message: `ld unrecognized option: --eh-frame-hdr`. Is there a way to remove this argument from the linking stage without having to create a custom target specification for linux builds?

I only found the `rustflags` key in `config.toml`, but as far as I know it only allows you to add additional flags and not to strip existing ones.

Comment: Isn't the better question, why the called linker does not accept this option? Are you sure you have the right linker in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by making sure that you are [passing the right `linker-flavor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#linker-flavor). rustc might have misidentified what linker you are using, and specifying that might help. Also ensure you are using the right linker. But if you really want to remove that argument, it is possible using some unstable features.

There isn't a general way to remove individual linker arguments. The `eh_frame_header` target attribute indicates if the linker should insert a EH (exception handling) frame header. Unstable rustc does have support for changing individual target options, but it is a bit complicated and can only handle `#![no_std]` binaries on some platforms. You might want to consider just calling the linker manually.

First, [dump the JSON target metadata](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/targets/custom.html) (using a nightly compiler) for the target you are compiling *to*, replacing `[target]` with a target triple like `thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-musleabihf`:

```sh
$ rustc -Z unstable-options --print target-spec-json --target [target] > target.json
```

`target.json` now has target-specific compilation information. On some targets (such as WASM), EH frame headers are disabled by default. If you see a line like this in `target.json`, you are already done (and shouldn't be getting that error):

```json
  "eh-frame-header": false,
```

If you don't see that line, then add it to `target.json` right after opening brace, like

```json
{
  "eh-frame-header": false,
  ...
```

You can now specify the path to `target.json` wherever a target triple would normally be. However, you now need to recompile the standard libraries (such as `core` and `std`) with the new target information. Otherwise, the compiler will tell you that `` the `target-17676080659170949227` target may not be installed ``. On unstable Cargo, you can use `-Z build-std`
to do that:

```sh
$ cargo +nightly run -Z build-std=core --target target.json
```

It will take a bit longer than normal, since it needs to recompile the `core` standard library. Not all platforms support compiling the fuller `std` library this way, but you can change the `build-std=core` to just `build-std` if you want to try to build the whole `std` standard library as well.